# Subspace contains the nullspace of a linear function, then subspace is itself either $V$ or the nullspace

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

For a linear functional $\phi$ on the vector space $V$ I claim that if $U$ is a subspace such that $\mathrm{null}{\phi} \subseteq U$ then it must be that either $U = \mathrm{null}{\phi}$ or that $U = V$.

I know that $\text { null } \phi =\{f \in V: \phi f=0\}$ and i know how to prove that $\mathrm{null}{\phi}$ is itself a subset of $V$. I'm having trouble applying any of that to prove my claim. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $U \ne null(\phi)$. Then there is $u_0 \in U$ such that $\phi(u_0)\ne 0$.  Set $u:= \frac1{\phi(u_0)}u_0$.  Then $u_1 \in U$ and $\phi(u_1)=1$.
Now let $v\in V$.
Then
$$
v = (v - \phi(v)u_1) + \phi(v)u_1
$$
with $v - \phi(v)u_1\in null(\phi)$ and $ \phi(v)u_1\in U$. So $v\in U$ and $U=V$.